# What is the difference between $ and jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I try to use `$("#div_id")` in `$(document).ready` it returns NULL, but when I use `jQuery("#div_id")` it returns the actual object!

Why is that happening?

**UPDATE:** I tried noConflict method without gaining any hints.

```
jQuery.noConflict()
function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)}

$.noConflict();
TypeError: Object function ()
    {
        return document.getElementById.apply(document, arguments)
    } has no method 'noConflict'
```

UPDATE 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
});

<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="123" />
```

When I run the following code in the console i got those results:

```
$("#test").val()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null
jQuery("#test").val()
"123"
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like firebug is override `$` to be document.getElementById

Comment: I load the page without enabling firebug, sometimes it prompts an error indicating that element not found. But other times it works fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Could other javascript libraries on your page be using the `$` variable?

`$` is just a variable that is used to alias `jQuery` and being a variable, anything could be assigned to it.

Comment: When is it aliased exactly? I tried to `jQuery("#checkbox1")` and `#("#checkbox1")` on a new html page without any plugins, the first worked like a charm the other returned NULL. I used jQuery 1.5.2 for that test

Comment: @wael34218 hmm... curious, I would need to see some sample code before I could hazard a guess as to what's going on. Can you post a simple page that reproduces this error?

Comment: I updated the post again, please check it out. If I put alerts to show $("#test")/jQuery("#test") value instead debugger, sometimes it works sometimes it dont

Comment: I told the same, but my interviewer seems like not agreed this. :(

Answer (score 10):

`$` and `jQuery` both are same except `$` is just an alias of `jQuery` which you can change or remove with `jQuery.noConflict` mode.

Comment: When is it aliased exactly? I tried to jQuery("#checkbox1") and #("#checkbox1") on a new html page without any plugins, the first worked like a charm the other returned NULL. I used jQuery 1.5.2 for that test

Comment: Try `$("#checkbox1")` instead of `#("#checkbox1")`

Comment: lol it was a typo error in my comment, it is `$("#checkbox1")` in my code

Answer (score 6):

$ is also used in [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/), which is a javascript framework like jQuery. 
It could be the case that your project also includes references to this framework.

For more info on how the prototype dollar works, go [here](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/).

You can make the two work together with the noConflict statement, as stated in the other answers. We're doing this in one of our projects, which uses the $(element) for legacy prototype code, and jQuery(element) for new jQuery code.

Comment: I am not using prototype at all, and I am not planning to. The idea is that I am only using jQuery and jQuery != $ ... that is confusing me

Comment: It could have been that you were working on a legacy app, with older references to other js frameworks. If that's not the case, ignore this answer =)

Comment: I was working on a very old code that is being developed by the ancient greeks when I discovered it. But when I tried it on a new html file that only includes jquery 1.5.2, the same problem aroused.

Comment: Could it be included in one of your masterpages?

Comment: No I dont think so, I wrote a simple html test page and the same behavior aroused.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like something has taken the $,
to reassign jQuery to $, try going:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have another library that uses $?

Comment: If you do have a look at the noConflict jQuery documentation, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I am not using any library that might override it

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` and `$` are the same - see jQuery source code:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Maybe you use another library that uses variable $ and then you have to solve naming conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Or you can use one of the following snippet (in it's body there will be no conflict of $):

```
// Method 1
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* some code that uses jQuery $ */ 
});

// Method 2
(function($) {
    /* some code that uses jQuery $ */ 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am only using jQuery without any other libraries. Try it out, make a simple html page that require jQuery and you will see the difference between $ and jQuery.