# What is the difference between "jQuery(selector)" and "$(selector)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between $ and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery)

I've noticed cases where "**jQuery**(selector)" is used instead of  "**$**(selector)", what is the difference between both of any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None. Normally, the `$` variable simply points to `jQuery`. You might be using `jQuery` instead in cases where the `$` is used by another library, or you are using it for other purposes in your code.

Comment: @Babiker $ is a function, and it points to the jQuery function. In javascript variables can be functions.

Comment: @Babiker: it is a function, stored in the variable named `$`.

Comment: `$` is simply a variable name, that in jQuery's case points to the jQuery main function. `jQuery` is the same, a variable pointing to that function.

Comment: More precise: Normally `$` and `jQuery` point to the same Function object.

Answer (score 1):

None. `$` is merely an alias to `jQuery`. However, when developing code for public consumption, you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`, as `$` might be assigned to something else, if they use more than one framework. Or just use a closure to make `$` a private variable, which is what most plugins do:

```
(function($){
    // Use $ normally here...
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just an alias for the same thing - to avoid conflicts in something like Wordpress, or frameworks that might import their own version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is used when you have another javascript library that uses the `$` variable. `jQuery`===`$`