# what is basic difference between $ Vs JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a js file which has several fn() and it was working fine but when at tached a js plugin file, i get error in firebug.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var innerHTML = $("#id_1").html();
     $("#Id_2").html(innerHTML)    
   });
```

above fn() was working but now i am getting error in firebug `$("#id_1") is null`.

if i use `jQuery` instead of `$` then it's workin fine. please see below the corrected function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var innerHTML = jQuery("#id_1").html();
     jQuery("#Id_2").html(innerHTML)    
   });
```

now my problem is, i have several js files and i have used `$` and now i might have to change `$` to `jQuery`. please give me any idea to avoid this.

Comment: Have you included aother library than jquery ?

Comment: check your code for "ID_2" seems you are missing "#" also id are case sensitive.. look for that too

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $ and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery)

Comment: Both those bits of code will work fine on their own.  Without seeing what libraries you've included it is hard to give you a concrete answer.  Please edit your question and add a minimal code sample that repros the problem (both HTML and JS).  Also try stripping out one library at a time until this specific error goes away.

Comment: @GauravShah: oops, typo mistake

Comment: @DidierG.: yes, i adding `wysiwyg` js library. http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/scripts/wysiwyg.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra library you are using ([wysiwyg.js](http://www.openwebware.com/wysiwyg/scripts/wysiwyg.js)) is also declaring a function `$()`:

```
/**
 * Get an element by it's identifier
 *
 * @param id Element identifier
 */
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

You should use [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 2):

`$` is just an alias for 'jQuery' .
Please make sure the library you are adding is not making any conflict with '$' . It generally happens when you try adding another framework with '$' as alias ex prototype.

use jQuery no Conflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict

Answer (score 2):

It is evident that the problem is caused by another JavaScript library defining the `$` function. You can work around it by:

```
var $copy = $;  // Copy the original value of $ to a temporary variable
$ = jQuery;

// Do everything that needs to be done with the jQuery library */

$ = $copy;  // Copy the old value of $
```

Or:

```
( function($) {
    // $ has been redefined for the scope of the current function
    // Do everything that needs to be done with the jQuery library */
} )(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing `#`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var innerHTML = $("#id_1").html();
     $("#Id_2").html(innerHTML);   // ; is optional here but good to have it    
   });
```

Assuming you have elements with `id` values  `id_1` and `Id_2`.
Just check case for `Id_2`.
[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/HSKMC/1/)

Comment: The semi-colon is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulPRO: Thanks, I got used to see `;` at the ends

Comment: Even though omitting the `;` is valid in javascript, I think it is better practice to explicitly use them to avoid misinterpretations

Comment: @DidierG.: Thanks for suggestion. I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `jQuery` and `$` is the same thing. If you look into jQuery source, you will find something like:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = function(){ ... }
```

In your case it seams, that the `window.$` variable was replaced with some other. It is possible, that some of your files called [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and the `$` variable got replaced.

Answer (score 0):

1. you are missing **'#'** in second id.
2. you are missing **';'** at the end of **id_2** line
3. you have given uppercase 'I' in 'Id_2'. make it sure that it is correct.

you can directly do it like

```
$("#id_2").html($("#id_1").html());
```

check fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nUZer/2/