# Why does Jquery have two different syntax-es for calling the same no conflict function?

Tags: jquery, syntax

From what I understand there are 2 ways of using `noConflict` (this applies to other functions as well) in jQuery:

1. `$.noConflict();`
2. `jQuery.noConflict();`

What is the difference between the two methods of calling functions in jQuery?

### EDIT

I know what it does, I need help clarifying the difference. When or for what reason should I use one or the other.

Comment: the `$` sign if often used by other libraries, to be sure that you wish to approach object `jQuery`, you can use `jQuery.*` instead of `$.*`. So `jQuery` and `$` are calling the same reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $ and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one case that was missed in the other post that I would like to clarify:

> `$` and `jQuery` both point to the `window.jQuery` object, so **they are one
>   and the same**. The reason some scripts use `jQuery` instead of `$` is to
>   **prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different
>   versions of jQuery which both also use the `$` variable**.

Taken from [What's the difference between `$` and `jQuery` and other n00b Qs](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/basics-what-s-the-difference-between-and-jquery-and-other-n00b-qs).

Answer (score 1):

See [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Could other javascript libraries on your page be using the $ variable?

$ is just a variable that is used to alias `jQuery` and being a variable, anything could be assigned to it.