# onclick change value of next or previus div

Tags: jquery, input

i am coding a buttons to change the value of the input between them.

my html is:

```
<td class="uneven">
    <div class="buttonbundle up">+</div>
    <input onkeyup="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" 
           onblur="bundle.changeOptionQty(this, event)" 
           class="input-text qty" 
           id="bundle-option-1-1-qty-input" 
           type="text" 
           name="bundle_option_qty[1][1]" 
           value="1" />
    <div class="buttonbundle down">-</div>
</td>
```

And if use onclick on buttonbundle up it must get the value of next input and put it again +1 , and if its minus, it must do -1.

I think it must be like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.buttonbundle.up').on('click',function){
        $val = jQuery(this).next('input').prop("value");
        jQuery(this).next('input').prop("value",$val);
    }
}
```

Or something like that.

Any idea?

Comment: `$val=$('input').val()` and `$('input').val($val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('.buttonbundle.up').on('click',function(){
        var input = $(this).next('input');
        var x = parseInt(input.val());
        input.val( x + 1 );
    });
    $('.buttonbundle.down').on('click',function(){
        var input = $(this).prev('input');
        var x = parseInt(input.val());
        input.val( x - 1 );
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6o7qpm6/)

## EDIT

Or wrapped in one function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.buttonbundle').on('click',function(){
        var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var x = parseInt(input.val());
        var y = $(this).hasClass('up') ? x+1 : x-1;
        input.val( y );
    });
});
// or
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.buttonbundle').on('click',function(){
        var input = jQuery(this).parent().find('input');
        var x = parseInt(input.val());
        var y = jQuery(this).hasClass('up') ? x+1 : x-1;
        input.val( y );
    });
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6o7qpm6/2/)

Comment: Nice code, but i don´t know why i can´t use it.
I was loading the js perfectly and it don´t makes any change...

Comment: @ntzz, I don't know, seems to work on the Fiddle... I added a function with `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: Oh thanks! it´s that!, What is the difference?
Why its better use $?

Comment: Could put a condition that if i use down and value is 0, dont make nothing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery

Comment: @ntzz, yes, add `if( y >= 0 )` before `input.val(y)`, see http://jsfiddle.net/p6o7qpm6/3/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two different handlers

For up

```
jQuery('.buttonbundle.up').on('click', function() {
   var $input = $(this).next('input');
   var $val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
   $input.val($val+1);
});
```

For down

```
jQuery('.buttonbundle.down').on('click', function() {
   var $input = $(this).prev('input');
   var $val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
   $input.val($val-1);
});
```