# $.parseJSON(...).each is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In a js file, i have the code below.

With this syntax is ok

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(category)).each(function() {  
    $(selector).append($('<option>').text(this.name).attr('value', this.contactCategoryId));
});
```

With this one that fail

```
$.parseJSON(category).each(function () {
    $(selector).append($('<option>').text(this.name).attr('value', this.contactCategoryId));
});
```

$.parseJSON(...).each is not a function

**EDIT**

that work fine

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(category), function () {
   ...
});
```

maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: The docs say parseJSON "returns the resulting JavaScript value." It doesn't return a jQuery object, so you can't chain it like that.

Answer (score 2):

[`jQuery.parseJSON(json)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting **JavaScript value**.

*so*

`$.parseJSON(category)` returns a javascript value.

*where as*

`$($.parseJSON(category))` returns jQuery object

As [jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) can only be used with a jQuery object. you are getting the error *$.parseJSON(...).each is not a function*

**In your case**, this is the correct way to use `jQuery each`.

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(category)).each(function() {  
    $(selector).append($('<option>').text(this.name).attr('value', this.contactCategoryId));
});
```

Comment: so, jQuery.parseJSON(json) and $.parseJSON(category) are the same thing

Comment: see this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery