# Is there any difference in speed using $. instead of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there any difference in performance using **$.** instead of **jQuery.** ?
I guess $ is the shorthand.
But in theory, does anybody know if it has any impact on performance using one or the other?

This question is not about $ versus jQuery in general. But the actual performance of using one or the other.

Comment: No. but `$` is easier to type

Comment: you can check this link show you different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery

Comment: Some other JavaScript libraries define a function called `$`, so it is safer to use `jquery`. About the performance there are no differences as it is an alias.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question - this is asking specifically about performance, and the other question is about conflicts with the use of `$`, and says nothing about performance!

Comment: Dunno about others but, I tend to use my $ pretty quickly.

Comment: I feel like on some deep down level `$` could be quicker performance wise, but negligible.

Comment: @Adjit Maybe that would be true on initial compile, but once it has mapped all the variables to memory the only slowdown is reading five more characters. This difference seems _more negligible_ than _negligible_.