# Javascript What is the difference between following lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the following lines of codes, When we are using jquery. Is there anyone of them more preferable?

```
<script>
alert("hello");  // 1. alert hello 
$(function(){alert("hello");}); // 2. Also alert hello
(function($){alert("hello");})(jQuery); // 3. It also alert hello
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $ and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262071/what-is-the-difference-between-and-jquery)

Comment: It is just a way of writing a self invoking function, https://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/03/13/understanding-jquery-plugin-pattern-and-self-invoking-javascript-function.html

Comment: instead of displaying "hello", alert `this` in all the place, like `alert(this)` and you will get more idea.

Answer (score 1):

- In the first line, you are just calling `alert()`.
- In the second line, you are trying to get a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or created by passing an HTML string ([more here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)). So the parameter is evaluated and `alert()` is called.
- In the third line, you are calling a self invoking function and passing jQuery as parameter but not using it. and `alert()` is called.

### TO SUM UP

The first line `alert("hello");` is definitely the best, as the last two lines are causing useless computations just to alert.